# Filter object where an attribute is equal to one of the attributes in another object - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in AngularJS.

I am trying to filter motorcycles by their categories. (Category is not one of the attributes of a bike model). Bikes have a unique code. I created my own categories json file which lists the specific bike models under each category.

For example:

Sport category has:

bike code: 12AB

bike code: 13AB

So when I filter by 'sport' I should only see those two bikes.

---

I have in my controller $score.models and $score.categories that each pull the correct data.

In my view, here is what I have so far.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <!--Sidebar content-->
  Bike Categories
  <select ng-model="_category">
    <option value="sport">Sport</option>
    <option value="tour">Tour</option>
    <option value="roadster">Roadster</option>
    <option value="enduro">Enduro</option>
    <option value="urbanMobility">Urban Mobility</option>
  </select>

</div>
  <ul class="models">
    <li ng-repeat="model in models | filter: _category"
        class="thumbnail phone-listing">
      <a href="#/models/{{model.code}}" class="thumb"></a>
      <a href="#/models/{{model.code}}">{{model.name}}</a>
      <p>{{model.marketingText}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

It does not filter by the model.code that is under a specific category. I believe I have to create my own custom filter but need some help on that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the structure of your models (`$scope.models` and `$scope.categories`)?

Comment: what does your json look like?